What to do in my gap year to transition from a US pure math undergraduate to an applied math masters in France?
I'm an international student who finished my undergraduate degree at a top-20 US university last December (double-majoring in math and comparative literature) and currently staying in my home country. The math that I studied as an undergraduate was pure math exclusively. In particular, I loved algebra, and my plan was to pursue a PhD in algebraic geometry. For example, I took courses in commutative algebra and 1st-year algebraic geometry, but never took a single course on any topic like ODEs, probability, statistics, programming, etc. My undergraduate GPA is 4.0/4.0.
However, my PhD application results were very disappointing. I was rejected by every program among the 15 or so PhD programs that I applied for. This might be due to that most of these are top US programs and hence way too selective. Due to short-sightedness in planning, I didn't apply for enough back-up programs.
The only two offers that I got were for the math MS programs at NYU and at the University of Bonn, respectively. The former has a tuition fee that I can't afford, and for personal reasons I'm also not a big fan of living and studying in Germany (especially in a small city like Bonn) - though I initially accepted Bonn's offer. On the other hand, my French is fluent, and Paris is a very ideal place for me to continue my studies. However, I didn't apply for any French universities this year, so if I want to go to France for my master's I'll need to do a gap year before applying again.
Moreover, in the last few months, due to changes in family situation, I became more and more aware that a career in pure math is way too competitive and financially unreliable. I decided that pure math is too risky a path to pursue, and that I would instead like to transition to applied math (most likely to operations research, modeling, or simulation) for my future studies.
Therefore, my current plan is to gap for a year, and then apply for M1 master programs in applied math at Paris universities like Paris-Saclay, Sorbonne, Ecole Polytechnique, and PSL. However, I'm worried that the lack of applied math courses on my undergrad transcript might have a negative effect on my chance of being accepted to these programs. I'm also worried that a gap year with no math experience might give grad school admissions people the idea that I'm not staying mathematically sharp enough.
My question is: given my pure math background, is there any activity I can do (preferably math-related, but not necessarily so) during my gap year that can prepare myself better for next year's master applications and also for my future studies of applied math?
A few options that I can think of (but not sure how to proceed with) include:
(1) Take some courses on topics like ODEs, numerical algorithms, optimization, etc. This sounds very good, but the biggest problem is I don't know where to take these courses. Are there any study abroad programs (maybe similar to the Budapest Semester in Mathematics program) that accept students in my situation? In fact, I'm also very happy to self-study these subjects, but I'm afraid that without official academic records, such self-study experience might not be well regarded by grad schools.
(2) Find an internship, whether in my home country or abroad. The main problem with this is, currently having few professional skills, I'm not sure what kind of internship can (a) agree to take me, and (b) have a positive effect on my future masters applications. I'm under the impression that most internship positions in my home country that are feasible for me (i.e. do not require a high level of professional skills) involve doing a large assortment of miscellaneous daily tasks that have very little to do with mathematics.
(P.S. I am aware that this question might depend too much on individual factors, but if that is the case, I am very much willing to edit it and make it more answerable. Thanks!)

"in Germany (especially in a small city like Bonn)" The following won't help much if you decided against the programme itself. But it might be worthwhile to mention that it takes only 30 minutes to go from Bonn to Cologne via train.

Bonn has 300,000+ residents and is tied in to the excellent train network. Why did you apply if you were going to reject it for such a trivial reason? Would you reject an offer from Princeton since it has a population 10 times smaller?

You should be able to shorten this to the relevant bits without the backstory

Look up “graduate non-degree studies” - in the US I was admitted in this scheme and took higher-level math courses with permission of the instructor during a gap year. You pay per course.

Frankly, rejecting Bonn was stupid. Thinking that applied math is less competitive may also not be very smart.

@Dirk: "rejecting Bonn was stupid" Was it? If OP believes that the programme doesn't fit their changed preferences, then why should one call their decision stupid?

@JochenGlueck Given the limited information in the post (only reason that Bonn is small and in Germany) it seems like an uninformed decision. Bonn is certainly one of the best places in Germany to do all kinds of math…

@Dawn Thank you so much, this is more or less the kind of option I'm looking for. However I discovered that many non-degree study programs don't sponsor F-1 visas for international students. Do you know of any university or department that offer visa sponsorship for students seeking non-degree status? Or maybe I should look for some "certificate programs" instead (those seem more likely to sponsor visas)?

@JonCuster The information in my post alone might indeed give the impression that I'm being capricious with planning. However, back when I was applying for grad school, (1) my intended career track was still pure math academia (in particular the field of AG in which Bonn is one of world's best institutions), not applied math; (2) consequently, it never occured to me that I will be finding a job and staying for work in the country where I do my master's, whereas now going to Bonn for master's would almost definitely entail finding an applied math-related job in Germany after I graduate.

@JonCuster As an international student, visa restrictions make it difficult for me to study in one European country (Germany) and find a job in another one (i.e. France). So now deciding whether to accept or reject Bonn is not just a matter of deciding where I'll do my master's, but also deciding where I'd like to work and live in the following years. I do recognize that Bonn is not that small under certain standards, but my home town is a city with population 70 times that of Bonn, so I feel rather constantly distressed by life in any city that's not really, really large.
